# Getting correct answer on MySQL but wrong for Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I was solving a HackerRank problem on SQL.
The question is:

*Query a list of `CITY` names from `STATION` with even `ID` numbers only. You may print the results in any order, but must exclude duplicates from your answer.

Input Format

The `STATION` table is described as follows:*
[Station](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlnyT.jpg)

My solution was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE (ID%2)=0
```

Now for this solution, I am getting the correct answer on MySQL but wrong answer on Oracle. Why is it so?
I am new to SQL so don't know about it much.

Comment: Why have two users voted to close this question? I think it's perfectly clear and shows sufficient effort, it might just need some rephrasing, but in that case, it's better to flag it as "needs improvement".

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mod()` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE MOD(ID, 2) = 0;
```

MySQL (and many databases) use `%` for the modulus function.  Oracle uses the `MOD()` function for this purpose.